# React Link address and id

Tags: reactjs, api, hyperlink, react-router, axios

New on dev and React I'm trying to make a mini app using the Discogs API.
A create a search that maps all the results and has  and loads the details of the album.

DISCLAIMER: I'm trying to do it without context to convert it afterward, I have to learn

The problem: I would like to have the browser's address example

```
<Link to={`${uri}`}> // uri: /U2-Pop/release/726622
```

http://localhost:3000/U2-Pop/release/726622

but like this the destination page doesn't load any API.

I have to get this

```
<Link to={`${id}`}> //id: 726622 (I added in axios.get https://api.discogs.com/releases/ )
```

http://localhost:3000/726622

And then works

Destination page:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getRecord(this.props.match.params.record);
  }
```

App.js :

```
 getRecord = async record => {
    const res = await axios.get(`https://api.discogs.com/releases/${record}`);

    this.setState({ record: res.data });
  };

<Route
          exact
          path="/:record"
          render={props => (
            <Record
              {...props}
              getRecord={this.getRecord}
              record={record}
            />
```

Any idea to how to do to get the address http://localhost:3000/U2-Pop/release/726622 , but in the same time pass the API to the destination page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `pass the API`? An API is an interface and not a variable or anything you can pass. I assume you just mean the `id`?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks. 
Correct, I mean to say: go to this address [http://localhost:3000/U2-Pop/release/726622]  and using an API to get the data.